# PHP Regex get custom doc params

Tags: php, regex, annotations

Is is possible to have from this class doc:

```
/**
 * @mapping(table='example')
 */
class Example {
```

output like this:

```
Array
(
  [table] => 'example'
)
```

and so on with multiple comma separated params like @mapping(table='example', else=something,...) using regex?

This is acutally my current code for parsing my reflection class doc content, which was found somewhere here on stack. Iam not that strong with regex, appreciate your help!

```
function parseAnnotations($doc)
{

    preg_match_all('/@([a-z]+?)\s+(.*?)\n/i', $doc, $annotations);

    if(!isset($annotations[1]) OR count($annotations[1]) == 0){
        return [];
    }

    return array_combine(array_map("trim",$annotations[1]), array_map("trim",$annotations[2]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not acutally. I just have problem to edit the regex make this output, but im able to get the content doc (via Reflection)

Comment: Have a look at [Doctrine Annotation Parser](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/1.10/index.html#introduction).

Comment: You could get the keys and values for that specific part using 2 capture groups `(?:^/\*\*(?:\R\h\*)*\R\h*\*\h*@mapping\(|\G(?!^)),?\h*([^\s=]+)=([^\s,=]+)`  https://regex101.com/r/E2xFbK/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks, awesome.. exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @JasonDerrick I can post it with an explanation if you want.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I used https://regex101.com/ for explanation, and its well explained, thank you sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example data, you might use the `\G` anchor to get continuous matches.

```
(?:^/\*\*(?:\R\h+\*)*\R\h*\*\h*@mapping\(|\G(?!^)),?\h*([^\s=]+)=([^\s,=()]+)
```

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^` Start of string
  - `/\*\*` Match `**`
  - `(?:\R\h*\*)*` Optionally repeat matching a newline and `*`
  - `\R\h*\*\h*@mapping\(` Match a newline, optional whitespaces `*` optional whitespaces and @mapping
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `),?` Close non capture group and match an optional comma
- `\h*` Match optional horizontal whitespace chars
- `([^\s=]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ times any char except `=` or a whitespace char
- `=` Match literally
- `([^\s,=()]+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ times any char except one of the listed chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BuJa7T/1)

Example

```
$re = '~(?:^/\*\*(?:\R\h\*)*\R\h*\*\h*@mapping\(|\G(?!^)),?\h*([^\s=]+)=([^\s,=()]+)~m';
$str = '/**
 * @mapping(table=\'example\')
 */
class Example {


/**
 * @mapping(table2=\'example2\', else=something,...)
 */
class Example {';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo sprintf("%s --> %s", $match[1], $match[2]) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
table --> 'example'
table2 --> 'example2'
else --> something
```